# is there an SQL Server equivalent of PostgreSQL "select * for update" without opening cursor

Tags: sql-server, locking

Postgresql allows me to lock the row while selecting it with the following syntax:

```
select id, amount from table where id = 1234 for update
```

This allows me to update the row while ensuring that concurrent reads who also want to update the same row will get updated and correct results.

Basically I can do something like this (pseudocode):

```
begin transaction
select id, amount from table where id = 1234 for update
if(amount == new_amount) then
  delete from table where id = 1234;
else
  update table set amount = amount - new_amount where id = 1234
end
commit transaction
```

The same syntax is allowed in Sql Server only for DECLARE CURSOR. Is there a way to read the row while locking it for update with just simple select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from T WITH (UPDLOCK)
```

The `WITH` hints are very flexible and well designed. I guess they are more precise and general than `for update`.